# Multi-tenant web service in WSO2 Data Services?

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-data-services-server

I want to build a web service where not every user can see all data. Therefor I need to store data in a multi-tenant fashion.

Quick example: Car dealers.

> dealer
>
> - ID
> - name
> - username
>
> car
>
> - ID
> - name
> - dealer_id (owned by)

Now the dealer calls the `get_my_cars` web service with his user credentials and should only see the cars that are owned by him. Something like:

```
SELECT car.id, car.name
FROM car
JOIN dealer ON car.dealer_id = dealer.id
WHERE dealer.username = %CURRENT_WEBSERVICE_USER%
```

But how do I get the `%CURRENT_WEBSERVICE_USER%` variable into the MySQL query? Or am I doing something horribly wrong here? How else would you filter data so everyone can only see his own data?

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Your usecase is not a multitenant usecase. What you need is to write a webservice(dataservice) and  secure it with usernametoken/basicauth. When an user calls that service with his credientials, you need to query the database and return back the results. Simple secured webservice is what you need.

Comment: Well, I have enabled UsernameToken security, but this only decides whether or not you can access the web service in general - it does not influence the data you see. dealer1 still sees the cars of dealer2. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Ok, I guess this is not possible. For our individual case, we will need to handle this on a higher application level.

Comment: After some more reading and experimenting I understand where the confusion came from. I want multi-tenancy on a data level (one data service offers separate data for multiple users), not on the level WSO2DSS offers it (different DSS tenants having different data services). The possibility to insert the username of the current data service call into the query would still be very handy.